# How is the NHS trying to delay the peak of covid-19?

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission

On march the 16th (probably) the NHS held a press conference ([Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0chs7bVQ8Y)) that includes (paraphrased)

> `We need to <u><b>delay and weaken</b></u> the peak so the NHS would not be overflown`

How? They didn't really explain the way behind **delay and weakening** the peak

Anybody could help?

Comment: This has been widely discussed and explained in the press. What research have you done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A  [summary](https://archive.org/details/linlabcovidpresentation20200316) on how to delay and weake the curve from Stanford researcher [Michael Lin, PhD-MD](http://med.stanford.edu/linlab.html):

[image]

Comment: Downvoted for [text as image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). Also, as Carey points out in a comment, this is an under-researched question and probably shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks, I don't care about the question being under-researched. That doesn't change the usefulness of the QA.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt We're getting bombarded with COVID-19 questions, many of  them trivially answered by typing the question into google and clicking on the first hit. Encouraging people to ask more questions they could answer themselves doesn't make this site more useful.